# JQuery instant search: how to make a second post request. and how to make a use enter key to search

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, search

I created an instant search similar to google search using JQuery.

Q1.
The post to search.php using search function searchq() then print out the returned result works fine, but the create_object.php can't get the variable txt (which has already been post successfully to search.php), any ideas on how to fix it?
Q2
I want to create a function that allow the user to be directed to the first search result(which is anchored with an url) when the enter is pressed, any idea how to achieve this? I tried something but it then quickly evolves into a messy nightmare.

Note that I didn't include the connect to database function here. Coz I think the database username and password setting would be different to yours.So please create your own in search.php to test it. The mysql is set with a table is called "objects", and it has one column named "name".

Thanks in advance!

```
 <html>
    <!-- google API reference -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- my own script for search function -->

    <center>
    <form method="POST">
        <input type="text" name="search" style="width:400px " placeholder="Search box" onkeyup="searchq();">
        <input type="submit" value=">>">
        <div id="output">
        </div>
    </form>
    </center>   

      <!-- instant search function -->
 <script type="text/javascript">

function searchq(){
        // get the value
            var txt = $("input").val();
            // post the value
            if(txt){
                $.post("search.php", {searchVal: txt}, function(result){
                    $("#search_output").html(result+"<div id=\"create\" onclick=\"creatq()\"><br>Not found above? Create.</div>");
                });
            }
            else{
                $("#search_output").html("");
            }


        };
function createq(){
    // allert for test purpose
    alert("hi");
    $.post( "create_object.php",{createVal:txt} );

}

</script>
    </html>
```

PHP file (search.php)

```
 <?php
if(isset($_POST["searchVal"])){
    //get the search
    $search=$_POST["searchVal"];
    //sort the search
    $search=preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i","",$search);
    //query the search
    echo "<br/>SELECT * from objects WHERE name LIKE '%$search%'<br/>";
    $query=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * from objects WHERE name LIKE '%$search%'") or die("could not search!");
    $count=mysqli_num_rows($query);
    //sort the result
    if($count==0){
        $output="there was no search result";
    }
    else{
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){

            $object_name=$row["name"];

            $output.="<div><a href='##'".$object_name."</a></div>";
        }
    }
    echo $output;
}
?>
```

php file (create_object.php)

```
 <?php
    if(isset($_POST["createVal"])){
        $name=$_POST["createVal"];
        var_dump($name);

    }

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I just made a simple change in your HTML. I removed the `onkeyup` attr, and added an `id` in order to have simpler jQuery selectors

```
<form method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="search" id="search" style="width:400px " placeholder="Search box">
    <input type="submit" value=">>">
    <div id="output">
    </div>
</form>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        var request;

        $("#search").on("keyup", function(e) {

            if(e.which === 13) {
                // Q2 -> Enter pressed
                var firstResult = $("#output").find("a").first();
                if(firstResult.length === 1) { // Just checking there is a result
                    window.location = firstResult.attr("href");
                }
                return false; // This prevents the form to submit
            } else {
                // Any other key
                searchq();
            }

        });

    });
</script>
```

#### Update

The reason of why you can't access the `txt` var from the `createq` function is because it's local to the `searchq` function, what means that outside the `searchq` function it doesn't exist at all.

Easiest solution is doing something like this:

```
var txt;
function searchq() {
    // Some code here
    // Use txt, not var txt
}
function createq() {
    // Some code here
    // Use txt, not var txt
}
```

#### New update

In `searchq()` you use

```
$("#search_output")
```

but it should be

```
$("#output")
```

You are also printing malformed HTML code in your `search.php`. It should be like this

```
$output.="<div><a href='##'>".$object_name."</a></div>";
// Note the missing > in the <a> tag
```

Comment: Q1. I tried it, the searching function even stop working. Could you try to do it without changing the html attribute,so the searching function could work at least. Q2  I tried to make the variable txt global, the createq function does get the variable, and I test it with alert function. However, the php file still can't get it, could you write a post function code, posting txt to create_object.php without callback function. (I didn't use var txt).

Comment: @pokemonking Just edited the answer based in your comment. The `$.post` without callback works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I am not so much familiar with PHP, so couldn't test the actual scenario. 
But as far as the javascript code, do check the following at your end:

**Q1:** You might have misspelled the function name 'createq' as 'creatq'

```
    ... <div id=\"create\" onclick=\"creatq() ...
    ..
    ..
    function createq(){
    ..
    }
```

**Q2** There is a keycode assigned for each key on the keyboard. For enter key, its value is `13`. You can get it by use of `event.which` in any event handler function. 
In this case, it can be get on `keyup or keypress` of the input field, something like below should do:

```
$(document).on('keyup keypress', 'input[name=search]', function(evt) {
    if (evt.which === 13) {
       // find the first search result in DOM and trigger a click event 
       // $("#search_output").find('a').first().trigger('click');


      // OR
      // find the url of the 1st link and use document.location to redirect 
      var redirectUrl = $('#search_output').find('a').first().attr('href');
      document.location = redirectUrl;
    }
});
```

Comment: Did you try the part where you trigger a click in a link? I don't think modern browsers would follow the link.. (Tested in Chrome 45.0.2454.85 for Ubuntu)

Comment: I changed the typo and the code above, the alert test works now, but the create_object.php still can't get the POST variable.

Comment: Also, for Q2, It's not working. I tried the similar thing before, it just not worked..

Comment: This is Weird huh, I did tried it in the console on some random site [Chome(Windows)], seems to be working then. I think I'll have to dig deeper why its not working and will share if found anything interesting. 
@pokemon king Anyways edited another approach, please retest.

Comment: @JoaquínO do you have any context on why trigger doesn't work or what are its limitations?

Comment: @Navendu actually `.trigger()` works. But it doesn't work like you would like in this example. It triggers the `click` event in this case, but doesn't follow the url in `href` attribute.. It's a jQuery decision. To actually trigger the click event in a link and follow it, use JS native `.click()` like this: `$('#search_output').find('a').get(0).click();`

Comment: Note that `.get(0)` gets the **first DOM node** element matched by the selector.

Comment: I tired the Q2 code, in both ways, and tested the redirectUrl does got the url I want. ( I add the test code to your code.) However, the page doesn't redirect to another url, it refreshed.

Comment: OK. got it now.. I must have validated on some anchors which have click event already bound beforehand.. thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @navendu TAT help TAT

Comment: it should work . what are the values of the url(before & after) and of redirectUrl

Comment: object.php?id=1 .. I don't think it is relevant though.

Comment: Can we chat on facebook or something? I can screen cut for you